# Showing Hidden Content and Adding Picture Effect using CSS

Tags: php, css, ajax

I have a php-mysql generated page. Which is almost like image gallery having 10*3 table of images.

I wish to add effect to picture.

1. I wish to color the picture frames according to time they were added to database. Like green for data added today, blue for a week old data, red for a month old data and orange for the rest.
2. I wish to attach a frame to them, which will have both image and some text.
3. I wish the picture to resize itself a bit to show it is in focus and show hidden div text along with previous text.
4. If possible I would like the focus box to show gif instead of jpeg with help of an ajax call.

I have seen example of first three query on some tutorial page but am unable to locate them now.

I can try to work upon fourth query on my own if I get a solution on first three.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the generated code output from your php? Also, CSS can not solve all this for you, as it has no idea when your pictures were added for instance.

Comment: pictures url are taken from mysql, thus i know when they are added.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is JQuery. Take a look at its effects and ajax functions. You may be able to implement those effects easily.

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/  -> Basic effects

http://api.jquery.com/category/css/ -> Manipulating CSS (for attaching a frame or everything on it)

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ -> Great Ajax functions

I hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: Can u help with some more examples??

Comment: If you click on each API function, you will have very illustrative examples in there

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is with PHP.

First check the date when the image has been uploaded and compare it with the current date. In that way, add classes to the images, i.e. for the 1 month old: "imgmonthold" and put the css styles standard in you stylesheet:

```
.imgmonthold {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

As the above poster said, for the other things you best use jQuery.

Comment: Possible too. I prefer to do it all myself without any extra's.. Just because I like the programming ;)

Comment: can u help me with some css examples. jquery and mootools are good for ajax calls.
I was looking at lightbox now.

Comment: In what way do you need some help? if you tell me exactly what you need I might be able to explain it to you. To be honest, i'm not a real pro ;) but I do know some tricks

Comment: Rune, can u help me with text re-sizing within a div tag, my text are overflowing. and some content are too less to increase size of all div tags.